# Get Company name from Assembly in Macro IDE - Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, macros

I've got a macro that I need to be able to get the "Company Name" from the project assembly. Can anybody tell me how I can reference the assembly to get the "Company"?

Comment: chirp chirp chirp... haha... ONE view in thirty minutes. Is this some kind of Stack Overflow record?

Answer (score 0):

```
  AssemblyCompanyAttribute[] attributes = (AssemblyCompanyAttribute[])Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyCompanyAttribute), true);

   if (attributes.Length > 0)
   {
       string company = attributes[0].Company;
   }
```

You should be able to modify that to get the company name